# Is there a two way lock that doesn't "lock" on both sides?

Tags: lock

I have a 135lb rottie that sort of barges into any room(connected to an outside door. All the other doors he cant go through) due to having weak doors. We are working on replacing them, but for now we just need a simple, cheap solution.

What I am looking for is a turn lock that doesn't need a key, or code to get into on any side. Sort of like a useless lock.

I have spent an hour a day looking, but to no avail, any suggestions?

EDIT: Thank you to those that responded, I think I found what I'm looking for, but more suggestions are welcome in case this doesn't work.
And regarding the dog breaking in **HES NOT AGGRESSIVE**. He just knocks to be let in. We just moved to an old house, and the doors are weak. He Isn't so much 'friendly' as he is "meh" about people. I know that he isn't fully trained, As we weren't sure if we were ready, but its too late to go back, and we love him too much anyway. THANK YOU AGAIN!!! =)

Comment: Will need to have a picture of the door sets/knobs/latches you are using now.  Most internal door sets should keep a door closed, if set right.

Comment: "weak door" does that mean that the dog is going _through_ the door or does the door just not latch securely? If it's just not latching securely, what makes you think simply replacing the knob will fix it? Simply fix the door/strike and do it right the first time instead of cutting a hole in the door for a lock that is a temporary solution but leaves a permanent hole

Comment: With all due respect, this is a dog-training issue, not a mechanical issue.  First: why are you restricting access? A properly trained dog will not pee or eat stuff in other rooms.  Next, something as simple as putting a large symbol of some sort on each door and working with the dog until they understand that symbol means "do not pass" will solve the issue.   Yes it works; I've seen it done with multiple dogs of multiple breeds.

Comment: @crip659, its an outside door, and one we use from both sides, so we would need a lock usable form both sides of the door, with no key

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I know that dog training is sometimes a divided opinion, so I wont share my methods, but he isn't aggressive. He just knocks on the door to be let in, and the door is from a 30 y.o house, so it just... gives. He usually sits outside and waits, but sometimes he gets hungry.

Comment: @FreeMan Weak meaning we have to use the top lock on the door that needs a key. but its a backyard door, and I'd rather not want to keep track of a key, incase I lose it. And a door strike sounds 1 way- and the doors are geting replaced with in 4-6 months, we just need something for two way purposes, and no key.

Comment: He knocks through doors but he's not aggressive.   Jesus.

Comment: @DMoore well, I can push one of them open with my pinky.... As I say, the're weak, and we have to lock them from the inside. but then anyone out back has to take a walk of shame to the front to get in... Hence the two way lock need

Comment: Yeah, that's bad.  Time to fix those latches, not super hard. I wish you would learn and use the correct words for the things you want. I used them in my answer, google any word you don't know.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica well the latches work. But they're one way, so anyone outback, gets to stay there until the doors unlocked... But I did google the word for a "Two way thumb-press no key lock" and similar, but to no avail. Hence why I'm here. And i know it's not hard, I Just need a working one delivered first! Edit:** Its not a handle i need, As the piece that sticks out doesn't go far enough in. I need a lock as those go deeper. the reason the doors aren't working is warped wood, so the doors are uneven**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As doorknobs go, that's called a "passage set".  No lock at all - no twisty-knob, no hole in the handle you jab with a turkey skewer to unlock, nothing.  However it does have a turnable knob, and the normal latch.  Learn to set up a latch and strike correctly.  Otherwise you are wasting your time.

Modern building codes are *super into* lever style door handles - you know the ones.  The Code authors **are actually dogs** who have infiltrated the Code authorities.  Dogs can operate levers!  They can't operate traditional knobs, because, no opposable thumbs.

If you're looking for a **deadbolt** with a handle on both sides, that is unusual but some lock systems will let your locksmith assemble this.  Talk to your local locksmith - the kind with a walk-in store that's been there for 20 years, where you go to their store.  (certainly DON'T deal with any out-call-only locksmiths where they come to you! That road trip isn't free, and some of them are crooks more interested in "casing your joint").

Soon you'll need to bite the bullet and train the dog.  Having a ill-mannered juggernaut like that is only going to hurt someone, get you sued into bankruptcy and the dog put down.

Comment: _" The Code authors are actually dogs who have infiltrated the Code authorities."_  <--Spit coffee on that one.  Might be true tho.

Comment: Well the problem is, its an outdoor house, and yes he isn't the most trained dog out there, so he just... pushes the door open. We've replaced the door knob, but to no avail. But regarding the "Soon you'll need to bite the bullet and train the dog" part, He is decent with people, doesnt like em, but doesnt attack em. Hes very "meh' like that xD